# Crashplan and samba printing problems after upgrade to 12.04

Tags: 12.04, printing, canon, crashplan

I upgraded from 11.10 to 12.04 (64bit).

after the upgrade Crashplan no longer works. It gives an error of getting "disconnected from the backup engine". Backups no longer take place.

I also had a Canon iP4600 attached to my Ubuntu computer that I was sharing via samba. Now printjobs get stuck in the queue, processing forever.

All these things worked fine in 11.10. I then did a clean install of 12.04, but no change. I searched everywhere but can not find solutions to these problems. I conclude that these must be bugs in 12.04.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to install Sun's Java SDK for CrashPlan (This was removed from the distro in 12.04) - Walkthrough Here: http://www.gaggl.com/2012/04/installing-java6-jdk-on-ubuntu-12-04/.

I've also been struggling to get CrashPlan to run.  Post back here if you have any updates/successes.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to the Crashplan problem:

It appears that the CrashPlan backup engine is running out of memory.

1. Stop the backup engine: http://support.crashplan.com/doku.php/how_to/stop_and_start_engine
2. Edit the below line in /usr/local/crashplan/bin/run.conf
3. Find this line (near SRV_JAVA_OPTS): -Xmx512m
4. Edit to something larger such as 640, 768, 896, or 1024. E.g.: -Xmx1024m

This sets the maximum amount of memory that CrashPlan can use. CrashPlan will not use that much until it needs it. I would recommend starting out with 768, and go higher if you continue experiencing problems.

1. Start the backup engine using the information at the above link, and then test to see if the issue remains.